# How to pass a PSR-6 compliant cache adapter in Laravel 6.X?

Tags: laravel, laravel-6, laravel-cache

I note there is a cache.psr6 container alias but if I use:

```
new Cache
```

As the instance, I get an error that getItems isn't available, which, I assume, means I am not passing a PSR-6 compliant cache instance. I'm using Redis if that changes the config in any way.

Is there an additional configuration to be done or am I passing this the wrong way?

The library I am using is: https://github.com/AlexaCRM/dynamics-webapi-toolkit/wiki/Tutorial

And the tutorial states:

> You can optionally supply a PSR-6 compliant cache adapter.
>
> $settings->cachePool = $cacheAdapter;

My question is, what is $cacheAdapter?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The adapter would be a [`Psr16Adapter`](https://github.com/symfony/cache/blob/master/Adapter/Psr16Adapter.php) over a cache driver which is how `cache.psr6` is bound in the default [`CacheServiceProvider`](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/6.x/src/Illuminate/Cache/CacheServiceProvider.php).

If you have redis configured as your default cache driver you would only need to set your cache pool to `cache.psr6`.

```
$settings->cachePool = app('cache.psr6');
```

However you may run into a `Class 'Symfony\Component\Cache\Adapter\Psr16Adapter' not found` error since `symfony/cache` is only a dev dependency in `laravel/framework`. You can resolve this by requiring it in your application.

```
composer require symfony/cache
```

Comment: Wonderful! Thank you for taking the time to explain the reasoning behind it and the dependency.

Comment: You're welcome. It just so happens I was also trying to set the cache pool and your question helped me to figure it out so I thought I'd share my findings